# Is there a way to for CVS (using Windows ) to Commit all subtending folders in different projects?

Tags: windows, cvs

I've got several projects:

P:\Projects\Common
P:\Projects\App1

I originally added each of the folders (and their sub folders) to CVS (using Tortoise).

Now I want to be able to just right clock Projects\ and "Commit" everytime I save anything in those folders.

However, it seems that \Project is separate from \Common which is also seperate from \App1

So if a file shows it' needs a checkin in \Common and I do a Commit on P:\Projects, it shows "no changes"

Is there any way to force all the subtending folders to commit?
Or is there a way to merge all of them? (Or even start all over with a new repository so that all of P:\projects are in the same "project" so that I can just do one checkin for all of them?

Answer (score 1):

You could either make a new CVS module that is a parent to all of your other directories or look into [alias modules](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/cvsmanual/Aliasmodules.html).

I have used alias modules to bring together multiple components into a single checkout (and therefore check-in) but you do need read/write access to the CVSROOT module to set it up.

This [walkthrough](http://www.solarorange.com/docs/cvs/shared.html) of someone setting up something similar may be useful to you.